# tutum node always at full memory consumption

Tags: docker, tutum

I have a tutum node and it's always near full memory consumption. If I upgrade the node to more memory, it's again full.

To be more specific: Once I started with a node and, say, 6 services I can't add another one because the node is always full. I have to restart from scratch or buy another node:

```
> watch -n 5 free

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4048280    3902288     145992      22796     310708    1334052
-/+ buffers/cache:    2257528    1790752
Swap:            0          0          0
```

The interesting thing is, that tutum itself does not know about that and thinks the node has more than 50% of his memory:

[image: Node memory usage]

What may be the reason for that? There is nothing else running on the node, it's been completly provisioned via tutum.

The underlying cloud provider is digital ocean, docker version is 1.8.3.

Comment: Can you get into the node and `docker ps -aq` and show the result? Is Tutum's "metrics" system container running? does the logs of this system container shows anything anormal? please paste them if you can

Comment: Believe it or not, memory usage dropped to 85% after i posted this. metrix is running. `docker ps -a` lists all my services plus a few tutum services (logrotate, cleanup, metrics, httpd, weave-daemon, events. I did not see any metrics logs.

Comment: So system containers are up and running. Do you mean there are no `docker logs metrics_container_name`? there should be a couple of lines like `Starting cadvisor / Starting to fetch node/container metrics every minute`. But no metrics are printed. That container only prints error messages, so if nothing is printed everything should be ok

Comment: Please note that the docker daemon can eat a high amount of memory if you are doing a high number of stdout writes. Due to the GC behavior of Golang, this allocated memory is only very slowly returned to the system, even though docker doesn't use it anymore.